# possible swt StyledText bug on osx

Tags: java, macos, swt, styledtext

I have a problem with a swt StyledText where a part of the text has to be colored.

When using following code on MAC OSX (works fine on windows) there is a problem when i enter multiple sequencial 'f' characters. There is alwso a problem when the 'f' is followed by a 'i' or 'l'. Other then that, there are no problems.

```
    editboxFreeSpt2 = new StyledText(grpSoundsLike, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);   
    editboxFreeSpt2.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener()
    {
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e)
        {
            editboxFreeSpt2.setStyleRanges(new StyleRange[0]);
            StyleRange newStyleRange = new StyleRange();
            newStyleRange.start = editboxFreeSpt2.getText().length() - 1;
            newStyleRange.length = 1;
            newStyleRange.foreground = red;
            editboxFreeSpt2.setStyleRange(newStyleRange);
        }
    });
    editboxFreeSpt2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
```

So the problem is that the last f/i/l character is not always colored like it should while the StyleRange is set properly.
I am using osx 10.7.5 with eclipse helios org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.6.2.v3659b.jar

So i think this might be a bug in SWT or in the native component of OSX.
What would be the best way to fix this bug or use a hack to override it?

Comment: Looks OK testing here on OS X 10.9, Eclipse Kepler. It may well depend on the font.

Comment: It seems to be something with the font indeed, with other fonts the problem does not occur.